# How to Properly update Java on OS-X

Tags: java, osx-elcapitan

I have installed and updated to the latest Version of Java.

I am running OS X 10.11.6 (15G31) on iMac.

The Java Control panel shows the correct verion and shows the link as:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Executing:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
```

Shows the correct version.

However, exectuting:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
```

shows an old version.

Executing:

```
whereis java
/usr/bin/java
```

Shows the link as /usr/bin/java

Yet trying to replace the soft link fails:

```
sudo ln -fs /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/bin/java
ln: /usr/bin/java: Operation not permitted
```

Even when using:
sudo bash (ie as root)

Any ideas?

Thanks
-jim

Comment: Can you show the output of `type -p java` from the prompt - it's most likely that your user's `PATH` is different from the path that's returned from `whereis` (which searches the value of `sysctl user.cs_path`). It sounds like there's a copy of java in the PATH before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: type -p java
/usr/bin/java

So it appears to be the same as "whereis" and "which" commands

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the folder name, `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` is actually an internet plug-in which is most likely only used for Applets.

The plain java installation on a Mac is located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` and this seems to be not updated automatically.

Therefore, you'd need to go to http://java.oracle.com and download and install the current Java version from there (it will update an existing Java8 installation automatically during the installation process). After that, `/usr/bin/java` will point to the updated version.

Comment: Appears, you must download the current JDK to change the pointer for /usr/bin/java. Just updating the JRE appears to have no effect. Regardless, the setup for Java on OS-X sucks.